# SSRS report graph not show 0 for value

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssrs-2008

When the graph in SSRS 2008,
Is it possible to show nothing as the value when there is no data for it? I still want to show 0 if the users wants to

[image]

Comment: Hopefully this link can help u http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207051

Answer (score 1):

Right click on top of the labels on the Report editor, and select "Series Label Properties".

On the General tab, on the Label data edit the expression to something like:

```
=IIF(#VALY=0,"",#VALY)
```